# Word Match Percentage

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I need to order values from the string range index based on what percentage of words matches query.

For example, if the search query is `aaa` and values:

```
aaa bbb ccc
aaa
ccc ddd aaa ppp
```

The output should be

```
aaa (100% match)
aaa bbb ccc (33% match)
ccc ddd aaa ppp (25% match)
```

I can pull all values from the index and loop through them, but I'm looking for a more efficient approach.